# How to trigger a payload from MetricKit for development and debugging

Tags: ios

The new [MetricKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metrickit?language=objc) announced at WWDC 2019 allows App developers to retrieve a metrics payload at most once per day.

During development and testing, it would be very helpful to be able to trigger the [didReceiveMetricPayloads:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metrickit/mxmetricmanagersubscriber/3131905-didreceivemetricpayloads?language=objc) API. Is that possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `Debug -> Simulate MetricKit Payloads` in Xcode 11.

Note: Make sure you are doing this on Real device as this doesn't work on Simulators.

Comment: Well that was easy! Thanks

Comment: Mine is greyed out, did you turn any settings on?

Comment: although i triggered it with the menu, my didReceive(_ payloads: [MXMetricPayload]) was never called...

Comment: Have you added the instance you're trying to receive the delegate as subscriber? `[[MXMetricManager sharedManager] addSubscriber:self];`

Answer (score 13):

Hopefully I can save you some trouble: this only works when you are connected to a real device. You cannot trigger `Debug -> Simulate MetricKit Payloads` on the simulator.

Comment: This is a clarification of [@taisuke hori's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57086718/3025856). It should have been posted as a comment, not an answer. That said, as @Sandeep Rana has since [edited this clarification into taisuke hori's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57086718/revisions), there's no need for it to be reposted as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, If you use Debug -> Simulate MetricKit Payloads, it will not collect the customed metric data as WWDC2019-417 said.

Comment: This should be posted as a comment on [@taisuke hori's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57086718/3025856).

Answer (score 0):

I left my app running overnight and logged any calls to the delegate function

`func didReceive(_ payloads: [MXMetricPayload])`

Anyone know why they wouldn't be called?